# How to load images after image upload via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've uploaded some photos via ajax. then the response is the json encoded image names.
I want to view images imminently after upload proccess.I've tried this:

**JS:EDITED**

```
$('#upload-form').ajaxForm({
        success: function(data) {
            $(".loader").hide();
            $("#status").html("");
            $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                $("#status").append("<img src='<?php echo base_url()."assets/img/"; ?>" + item.name +"' />");
            });
            return false;
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            $(".loader").hide();
            return false;
        },
        error : function(xhr) {
                $("#status").html(xhr.responseText);
                $(".loader").hide();
        }
    });
```

but still no luck. How can I do this?

Comment: Just a nitpick, you should name the first parameter in your success something other than xhr, it isn't an xhr object.

Comment: Why is there a PHP tag in your JavaScript?

Comment: @MattBall, It works matt.it gives me the full url.

Comment: @KevinB, Ok.Can You tell me what exactly an xhr object is?

Comment: Also, you appear to be... looping twice, you can combine those two $.each calls into one, and get rid of `i` because you have `index`

Comment: @1linecode This is the documentation for the XHR object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: That's a question you should be answering. What is the xhr object that you are cycling through? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: jQuery has no `$("#status").appendChild` method, it's `$("#status").append`

Comment: Sure, but the PHP is not useful information in this context. What matters is the code that the browser executes - which is the _generated_ JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trying to fix the code...

I assume ajaxForm is some sort of plugin, and xhr works as you think it does

No need for two loops, and no need for an intermediate array, you can create image nodes directly.

```
var baseUrl = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "assets/img/"; 

$('#upload-form').ajaxForm({
    success: function(xhr) {
        $(".loader").hide();
        $("#status").html("");
        var images = "";
        $.each(xhr, function(index, item) {
            images += "<img src='"+ baseUrl + item.name + "' />";
        });
        $("#status").append(images);
        return false;
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
        $(".loader").hide();
        return false;
    },
    error : function(xhr) {
            $("#status").html(xhr.responseText);
            $(".loader").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: just made a change... try again